# What is the dot product between these two vectors?

Tags: vectors, inner-products, orthogonality

[image]

I understand that for vectors $u$ and $v$,  $cos\theta=\frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}$

This means that $u\cdot v= |u||v|\cos\theta$

So the dot product can only be negative when $\cos\theta<0$

$\cos\theta<0$ when $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}$

$\cos\theta>0$ when $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\cos\theta=0$ when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$

My answers are as follows:

a) $a\cdot f$ positive since $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

b) no clue how to do

c) $d \cdot b$ positive since $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

d) $a \cdot b$ negative since $\theta>\frac{\pi}{2}$

e) $c \cdot e$ zero since $\theta=0$

Can someone please verify my answers for a, c, d, e? And how do I do part b)?

Comment: Please tag questions appropriately. This is not about calculus, but it is about orthogonality, dot product and vectors...

Comment: When comparing angles between vectors, picture them with the same origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c\cdot e\neq0$$Since the dot product is $0$ if and only if the vectors are orthogonal, as $\cos(\pi/2)=0$. $c$ is in fact a $\pi$ turn away from $e$, so their dot product is as negative as it gets.

You were on the right track; for $b)$, make the same observation you made with $d)$: the turn between $f$ and $c$ is greater than $\pi/2$, so the dot product is negative.

Comment: thanks for the correction on part e). For part b) I'm still confused because for all the other parts I was able to see the two vectors "attached" to each other. Should I just put the head of f to the tail of c? and if so I get an acute angle?

Comment: You should make sure they are not tip-to-tail, as in adding, but rather they share the same base point, so you can see their directions clearly. Slide $c$ down the line $d$ until its base is at the base of $f$, and you observe the angle to be obtuse - hence a negative dot product @user130306

Comment: got it, thanks so much for the help!